# Getting a "move target out of bounds" exception when trying to click at a specific x and y coordinate

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So some weird stuff, could just be im unfamiliar with a specific rule related to the MoveByOffset() method.
So I have the x and y coordinates that I need to move the mouse too, I know they're the right coordinates because I can actually see it happen when my test reaches this line of code:

`actions.MoveByOffset(842, 663).Click().Perform();`

The problem arises when I interact with a separate element, I click a button to open a drawer to validate some information, Once my script validates what it needs to it closes the drawer and attempts to execute

`actions.MoveByOffset(842, 663).Click().Perform();` once again.

I dont scroll or really change anything on the screen other than open a drawer and close it.

But Its at this point where ill get the exception
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : move target out of bounds
I have it currently in a try catch block and even when I catch the exception it still throws the same exception at me.

Any help or advice or info would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

`MoveByOffset(x, y)` means Move By Offset from your current position.
Performing `MoveByOffset(xOff, yOff)` you move pointer into `(currentX+xOff; currentY+yOff)`.
So first time it is 0+842 and 0+663, second time it is 842+842 and 663+663.

If you need to go to element use `moveToElement()`.
To be sure you don't reach bounds of viewport you can use something like `driver.manage().window().getSize()`.
it is Java code, but I believe c# has such operators.

Comment: Good catch. I was also having same problem, now I got it. Thank you!